# Sphinx override app config value for extension

Tags: python, python-sphinx

One of the sphinx extensions i installed has a config named: drawio_binary_path
In the extnesion, there is a value set for it.
If i try to override it in my conf.py using:
`app.add_config_value("drawio_binary_path", 'C:\draw.io.exe', "html")` it throws an error: `Config value 'drawio_binary_path' already present.`
Is there a way i can override the value?

Ref: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/_modules/sphinx/config.html

https://github.com/modelmat/sphinxcontrib-drawio/blob/master/sphinxcontrib/drawio/__init__.py

Comment: In your `conf.py`, did you try `drawio_binary_path = "C:/draw.io.exe"`? (I think Python treats forward slashes as directories on Windows, just like all other platforms, else it might escape the subsequent character.) The README of the extension appears to align with the standard way of setting values in Sphinx.

Comment: Thank you. I was supposed to directly set the value like you said:
drawio_binary_path = "C:/draw.io.exe"

Answer (score 0):

Directly set the value in the config.py
`drawio_binary_path = "C:\draw.io.exe"`
instead of using the `app.add_config_value` function.